# Google Material Icons as array - any ideas?

Tags: php, arrays, icon-fonts

I'm implementing the Google Material Icons into my application - https://www.google.com/design/icons/

I would like to be able to populate a `select` field, so that it displays either the names of the icons, or the icons themselves, with the `value` of the `option` being the numeric character reference (so it's compatible with browsers that don't support ligatures - IE < 10).

I want to get all of the icons into an array so I can generate the `option` elements of the `select`. So, this sort of thing:

```
$icons = array(
    "&#xE84D;" => "3d rotation",
    "&#xE84E;" => "accessibility",
    etc. etc.
);
```

I would rather not have to sit and manually create this array from all 750 items, so I am wondering if anyone has any ideas for an automated way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the `MaterialIcons-Regular.ijmap` json file that comes along with the fonts.

PHP example show:

```
// Get the contents on the ijmap bundled with the icon font
$list = json_decode(file_get_contents('path/to/MaterialIcons-Regular.ijmap'), true);
$icons = []; 

foreach ($list['icons'] as $i => $data) {
    $icons[$i] = $data['name']; 
}
```

Comment: I didn't even realise this file existed! Thank you very much, you've saved me hours every time Google add new fonts.

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to do this in a semi-automated way.

Here's the array for anyone else who might need it: [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/LQcV44Bt)

Hope this helps someone!